# Write current URL to console in TestCafe

Tags: testing, console, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a variable "currentPage" which I want to set to the current URL on the running page.
But to see that the URL is correct I want to print it to the console. What ever I try I keep getting "not defined", "object", ...
If I on the other hand use the "await t.expect(...)" method and make it fail then I see the wanted URL.

```
const getURL = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href);
console.log(getURL) //does not work
console.log(getURL()) //does not work
```

Can I write it to console output?
If so then I guess it should also be possible to do something like 
"currentPage = getURL()" but I get:

```
current page function __$$clientFunction$$() {
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've missed the `await` keyword before calling ClientFunction. Please refer to http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client.html#executing-client-functions.
 
I suggest you write it in the following manner:

```
const url = await getURL();
console.log(url);
```

Comment: if you ever make an error in test cafe, double check you're awaiting things. As someone who's been using it a lot over the last few months. That's my most common error

Answer (score 2):

```js
const getURL = await ClientFunction(() => window.location.href)();
console.log(getURL) //will work
```

Just make getURL() self invocation function. IMHO